# Postgresql Select rows and update column

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-update

I have SQL Select query with where clauses. For e.g

```
select * from table where status = 1
```

And how can I update single column with selected rows simultaneously while selecting? I want to mark selected rows, to avoid reselect on the next loop. Something like:

```
select * from table where status = 1; update table set proc = 1 where id in (select id from table where status = 1)
```

But this query will not return results.

Comment: There is only one table involved? BTW: don't name your tables `table`; invent some other meta-syntactic names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the returning clause:

```
update table 
    set proc = 1 
where id in (select id from table where status = 1)
returning *;
```

(Btw: I assume the inner select is not actually selecting from the same table, because then the statement does not really makes sense as it could be rewritten with a simple `where stauts = 1`)